# Lock an object in Java

Tags: java, time

How can a Java object be locked for a certain amount of time (e.g. 20 seconds)? By locked, I mean that the object cannot be accessed in that time.

Comment: what type of object

Comment: Out of curiosity why would you want to do this?

Comment: i have class Book, and i need to lock instance of that class

Answer (score 2):

You could synchronize all of the methods, and have a `lock` method that just waits for 20 seconds and returns.

```
 public  synchronized void lock(){
            try {
                Thread.sleep(20 * 1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
        }
```

Remember the synchronize all of the methods, and keep all fields private. (Everything on the interface should be `synchronized`)

If you need to do this for a general object - i.e., one you can't write or specify yourself - then it's time to learn how Monads work:

```
public class Lockable<T> {

    private T _t;
    public Lockable(T t){
        _t = t;
    }

    public synchronized void perform(Consumer<T> consumer){
        consumer.accept(_t);
    }

    public synchronized <R> R get(Function<T, R> function){
        return function.apply(_t);
    }

    public synchronized<R> Lockable<R> map(Function<T, R> function){
        return new Lockable(function.apply(_t));
    }

    public synchronized void lock(){
        try {
            Thread.sleep(20 * 1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Thread.currentThread.interrupt();
        }
    }

}
```

The above isn't 100% unbeatable, but so long as you'd don't let un-wrapped references loose, it should be okay.

Comment: Can you please provide an example ?!?

Comment: than you for the example but a question still in my head do i use this method or a timer instead of it

Comment: @YagamiLight You can measure time whichever way you prefer, I don't think it makes a difference here

Comment: @DavidPérezCabrera Yeah, it definitely has its flaws. Was fun to write, though.

Comment: This code improperly handles the `InterruptedException`. Take a look at _Java Concurrency in Practice_ by Brian Goetz, et al., for the proper handling.

Answer (score 2):

There is no *general* mechanism to lock objects in Java.

You can define your own class of lockable objects (e.g., as suggested by David Pérez Cabrera and Edward Peters), but there is no way to lock arbitrary objects that weren't *designed* to be lockable.

Comment: Do you not consider `synchronized (foo)` as a way to lock on the object pointed to by `foo`?

Comment: @LewBlock, that would depend on what you mean by "lock".  If you look at the question, it clearly says, "By locked, I mean that the object cannot be accessed."  Synchronizing on an object does not do what the OP asked for:  It does not prevent other threads from accessing or modifying the object.

Answer (score 1):

To be more precise, all of its method must be `synchronized` and all of its field must be `private`.

```
public class LockeableObject {

    private String fieldFoo;

    public synchronized void lock() throws InterruptedException{
        this.wait(20 * 1000); // 20 seconds
    }

    public synchronized void foo() {
         ...
    }

    public synchronized void foo2() {
         ...
    }

}
```